# SQL - First n non null columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have 30 columns like p1, p2, p3,......,p29, p30.
Out of them, any 6 consecutive values will be non-null and the rest are all none.

I need to write an SQL query (preferably Redshift) to get all of them into 6 columns. Say a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6

Eg. If I have 50 rows of data with 30 columns with a lot of nulls. I'll be turning it into 50 rows of data with those 6 non-null values of a row.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: This sounds like a bad data model. Probably those columns should be rows instead (the increasing numbers in the column names are a strong indicator for that)

Comment: It's always constant the 30 columns don't ever increase or decrease.
@a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this.  One method is to unpivot and then re-aggregate -- assuming your table has a primary key:

```
select pk,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then p end) as q1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then p end) as q2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then p end) as q3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then p end) as q4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then p end) as q5,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then p end) as q6
from (select pk, p, row_number() over (partition by pk order by which) as seqnum
      from ((select pk, 1 as which, p1 as p from t) union all
            (select pk, 2 as which, p2 as p from t) union all
            . . . 
           ) t
      where p is not null
     )  t
group by pk
```